# Memory Leak issue in opencv

Tags: opencv, memory, memory-leaks

In my project i used CvPoint2D64f* function to store corners of the chessboard image manually.Now i got memory leak error due to un released memory.I tried both free(Corners) and 
delete[] Corners.But after 11 hours it gives same memory leak error.i had a confusion.Which one is correct method to release memory?

```
int main()
{
    CvPoint2D64f* Corners = 0;
    Corners = new CvPoint2D64f[25];
    ......

    free(Corners);
    return; 
}
```

i used c library of opencv 2.1

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want it to be 'C', you can't use 'new', that has to be:

```
Corners = (CvPoint2D64f*) malloc(25 * sizeof(CvPoint2D64f));
...
free(Corners);
```

---

but honestly, your problems are due to using an outdated version(2.1) and an outdated api(c)

those manual memory management issues were the main reason for the opencv devs to switch to c++.